# How can I find my contract method from a WCF message header Action?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, soa

I have created a class that implements IDispatchMessageInspector and in the AfterReceiveRequest method I can get the action in this form: "http://example.com/contract_name/operation_name"

Is there a *good* way that I can get figure out what method that is in my contract interface? Can I do it using the same code that WCF uses to find what method to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that info that late in the game; you have to grab it from the OperationDescription objects when you're applying your custom behavior to insert your IDispatchMessageInspector implementation and put it somewhere you inspector can get at.

I have some information on how to correlate SOAP action headers and operations [here](http://winterdom.com/2006/10/operationdescriptionandthesoapaction).

Some actual sample code on how to do this [here](http://quickcounters.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74794#1359792).